# Combinations - KNN fitted on pairs of features

Tags: python, loops, combinations, knn

I am trying to fit a KNN model on each pair amongst the 4 features indicated below. The 2nd for-loop is not producing any result. I have tried `for i, pair in enumerate(feature_comb)` as well but the code in the loop is again not performed.

The first loop worked fine, printed each pair of feature names in list. Why is it not working in the 2nd case? Thanks in advance.

```
data= data.dropna()
feature_choices= ['fg_pct',
'ast',
'blk',
'tov' ]
feature_comb= combinations(feature_choices, 2)
for pair in feature_comb:
    print(list(pair))
# We have 6 pairs of features to fit.
# predict for column 'cat', produce test r2 for each pair 
categories= pd.unique(data.loc[:,'cat'])  #{0,1,2}

# For each pair of features (key), save the test r2 as the corresponding value
score_dict={}
for pair in feature_comb:
    response= data.loc[:,'cat']
    ytr, yte= train_test_split(response, test_size= 0.2)
    features= data.loc[:, list(pair)]
    ss= StandardScaler()
    features_sc= ss.fit_transform(features)
    xtr, xte= train_test_split(features_sc, test_size= 0.2)
    xtr= pd.DataFrame(xtr, columns= features.columns); xte= pd.DataFrame(xte, columns= features.columns)
    
    knn= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors= 3)
    knnmod= knn.fit(xtr, ytr)
    r2= knnmod.score(xte, yte)
    print(r2)
    score_dict[list(pair)]= [r2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `combinations` returns an iterator.  After your first loop, the iterator has been completely consumed; there's nothing left.  It's at the end.  So, your second `for` loop has nothing to do.

If you really want to print the results first, make it a `list`.  You can consume that as many times as you want:

```
feature_comb = list(combinations(feature_choices, 2))
```

Comment: It seems that it will only work if feature_comb is PRE-defined as a list. As I tried ```for pair in list( feature_comb)```, where feature_comb is still the combination object, the iterator is 'consumed' on its first loop as well

Comment: Right.  You have to extract it into a list, and then you can reuse the list.